# Angular 2 ng-bootstrap ngb-tabset and ngb-tab - how load the data from dynamically

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

IN Angular 2 ng-bootstrap, can you give me direction in how I can at run time, take an object representing 3 tabs (title and panel data) and have a ng bootstrap tab control use that data to populate itself?

Comment: Where is is request standing now? Did you get a solution to dynamically generate tabs and their content

Answer (score 0):

tabs of [ngbtabset](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabset/tabset.ts) is not an input property, doesn't support binding.

But tabs with bootstrap is easy, I think you can write a custom component.